# Opposite of Array.reduce() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Array.reduce() takes an array and combines elements from the array with an accumulator until all the elements are consumed.

Is there a function (often called "unfold" in other languages) that starts with a value and keeps generating elements until a complete array is produced (the accumulator is depleted)?

I am trying to do this as part of converting between arbitrary bases.  The code as I have it is as follows, but I would like to eliminate the raw loop.

```
var dstAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGH";
var dstBase = dstAlphabet.length;
var wet = BigInteger(100308923948716816384684613592839);
var digits_reversed = [];
while (wet.isPositive())
{
  // var digitVal = wet % dstBase
  var divRem = wet.divRem(dstBase); // [result of division, remainder]
  wet = divRem[0];
  digits_reversed.push(dstAlphabet.charAt(divRem[1].toJSValue()));
}

return digits_reversed.reverse().join("");
```

Comment: "until a complete array is produced" --- can you provide a formal definition for this? What is a "complete array"? How would that hypothetical function know if the array is already complete or not?

Comment: zerkms: perhaps you provide a second function that determines whether the value has been depleted?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to convert your number to base 18...why not just do `(100308923948792839).toString(18)`?

Comment: tewathia, you are right, but that only works for up to 32-bit numbers (I have modified the example).

Comment: most programming languages refer to this type of function as "unfold".

Comment: I found this article researching on the topic. Might be an interesting read about folding and unfolding... http://raganwald.com/2016/11/30/anamorphisms-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tewathia's comment seems like the idiomatic way to do it, but I guess if you want to do it the hard way, you could just write your own recursive primitive, like:

```
function unreduce(accumulator, operation, stopPredicate, ret) {
    return helper([accumulator, ret])[1]

    function helper(vals) {
        if (stopPredicate(vals[0])) return vals[1];

        return helper(operation(vals[0], vals[1]));
    }
}
```

Which you might want to modify a bit to preserve `this` for the callbacks.

I'm not sure how great that is. It's kind of awkward with the `operation` callback needing to update both the accumulator and return values. The outer function can't save `operation` from having to return a length-2 array.

Answer (score 4):

```js
// These days you can do it in one line:
const unfold = (accumulator, length) => length <= 0 ? accumulator : unfold([length, ...accumulator], length -1)

// invoke it like this:
const results = unfold([], 5)

// expected results:  1,2,3,4,5
console.log(results.join(','))
```

Since we're looking for a concise way to generate a given number of elements as an array, this "unfold" function does it with recursion.

The first argument is the accumulator array.  This needs to be passed along, and eventually is returned when it holds the entire collection.  The second argument is the limiter.  This is what you use to dimension your resulting array.

In each call, we first test if the base case is reached.  If so, the answer is easy: just return the given array.  For the general case, we are again unfolding, but with a smaller value, so we prepend one value to accumulator, and decrement length.

Since we're using the spread operator and a 'computed-if' the function is concise.  Using the arrow style also lets us avoid the 'function' and 'return' keywords, as well as curly-braces.  So the whole thing is a one-liner.

I basically use this technique as a for-loop substitute for React JSX, where everything needs to be an expression (Array.map()).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include an explanation of the code and how it solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in Javascript is [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (or alternatively [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)). You can use it with any [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) object to generate an array:

```
array = Array.from(iterator); // same as array = [...iterator];
```

You *can* create an iterator by calling a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```
iterator = generate(params);
```

Generator functions use the special keyword [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) to return their results (or [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) to return all results from another iterable). And they are depleted once they return:

```js
function* convertBase(wet, alphabet) {
    const base = BigInt(alphabet.length);
    wet = BigInt(wet);
    while (wet > 0) {
        const digitVal = Number(wet % base);
        wet = wet / base;
        yield alphabet.charAt(digitVal);
    }
}

console.log(Array.from(convertBase(100308923948716816384684613592839, "0123456789ABCDEFGH")).reverse().join(""));
```

Alternatively you can implement the iterator yourself without a generator function:

```js
console.log(Array.from({
    wet: BigInt(100308923948716816384684613592839),
    base: BigInt(18),
    alphabet: "0123456789ABCDEFGH",
    [Symbol.iterator]: function() {
        return this;
    },
    next: function() {
        if (this.wet > 0) {
            const digitVal = Number(this.wet % this.base);
            this.wet = this.wet / this.base;
            return {value: this.alphabet.charAt(digitVal)};
        } else {
            return {done: true};
        }
    }
}).reverse().join(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.map((..) => { return [ .. ]; }).flat(1);
```